# Thin Purple Horozontal Line Sony A7s ii

Tags: sony

I have a Sony a7s ii with a Sony Vario Tessar 16-35mm lens. When I take a photograph or video, this thin purple line appears at the bottom of the screen. Here are some examples.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/212455014273253377/227022506068803584/DSC00303.JPG

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/212455014273253377/227022521566887936/DSC00304.JPG

It does not appear all the time. Sometimes in some photographs it goes away. I will move the camera to a different spot and I see the line disappear. Point it in a different direction, and there it appears again. It's always in the same spot at the bottom of the screen. Any idea as to what this is, and how to fix?

Comment: That has to be a problem in the sensor electronics, i.e. a hardware defect. is it still under warranty?

Comment: Yes I believe so. I'll take it into Best Buy and figure that out.

Comment: See Michael Clarke's comment on my answer but intended for you - I think the system may not automatically send that to you. | IF the camera was new and you have owned it for a moderately short while I would resist receiving a used camera as replacement. If this is a purportedly new camera it should come in perfect order and should certainly not have a dirty sensor - and certainly not a sensor fault.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be most concerned about that line - it should NEVER happen.

It's about 99.9% liable to be a camera issue and probably sensor related.

VERY occasionally the most unlikely problems can be caused by lens contact issues (it seems the electronics can become 'confused' in ways that make no apparent sense). So, turn the camera off, and try unlocking the lens, turning and reseating it a few times and see if this eliminates the problem. This causes the contacts to re-seat and occasionally very minor oxidation or contamination can cause  problems.

Also, just breaking and remaking the lens circuitry as above may 'descramble' the camera's microcontroller's mind - you'd hope that cameras never 'crash' - but it does happen. I've seen very strange problems cured in this manner.

Finally, turn off camera, remove battery, leave a few tens of seconds, replace battery, turn on again and try a full camera reset (an option available in a usually obscure menu). This is getting somewhat desperate but is worth doing before committing a camera for warranty repair. Faults as solid and repeatable as the purple line fault should not be caused by errant software but, with software, almost anything can happen, and sometimes does.

If none of the above fully and permanently  cure the purple line problem, a warranty repair is in order. While they have the camera, if the spots you mention were there from new, ask them to clean the sensor as well. (If they do not replace it due to the line).

Comment: Yeah, the camera is defective. If you just bought the camera and can return it for what you paid or swap it for another new one then that should be your first option. If you can't return it for the full price you paid then you need to pursue a warranty repair. If the sensor needs to be replaced, don't be surprised if the company responsible for the warranty offers to send you a reconditioned camera (same model) in lieu of fixing the one with the bad sensor.

Comment: This was a gift for me, but when it was purchased from Best Buy there was a warranty. I will check into this tomorrow, hopefully it will be repaired or I can get a brand new one.